# Are the strings supposed to be directly over the pickups?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, strings, pick-ups, bridge

I just bought a Squier affinity strat and noticed that the strings do not directly go over the center of the pickups.

This is especially the case for the bridge pickups which are at an angle.

Is this normal? And does it affect the guitar's ability to produce a sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's always going to be a slight misalignment, if you think about it, due to the fact that the strings are at a certain width at the bridge, but narrower at the nut. This sometimes means that the bridge pup, especially if at an angle, is spaced too narrow, while the middle may be just right, and the neck pup is a bit wide, due to the reducing taper.

Due to the proximity of the strings to the poles anyway, it's not a huge problem, and we seem to have been blissfully unaware that it *is* a problem for all the 60+ years that Strats and Stratalikes have been around.